# How To Debug PerformSelector in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin.mac

I'm trying to use `PerformSelector` to send a message to an object on macOS 10.15 with Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638).

`RespondsToSelector` returns `true`, but then actual `PerformSelector` crashes the app if a method expects arguments.

The class defines these instance methods (among others):

```
#import <Foundation/NSTask.h>

__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
@interface NSConcreteTask : NSTask
...
- (void)setStartsNewProcessGroup:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setLaunchPath:(id)arg1;
- (void)launch;
...    
@end
```

Sending a selector without arguments works:

```
    var t = new NSTask();
    ...
    var launch = new ObjCRuntime.Selector("launch");
    if (t.RespondsToSelector(launch))
        t.PerformSelector(launch);
```

This launches the task exactly like when I call `t.Launch();`.

But when I try sending messages to any of the methods with arguments, the app randomly crashes:

```
    var NO = NSObject.FromObject(false); // NSNumber.FromInt32(0) doesn't help, either
    var setStartsNewProcessGroup = new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setStartsNewProcessGroup:");

    if (t.RespondsToSelector(setStartsNewProcessGroup))
        t.PerformSelector(setStartsNewProcessGroup, NO);
```

or

```
    var setLaunchPath = new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setLaunchPath:");

    if (t.RespondsToSelector(setLaunchPath))
        t.PerformSelector(setLaunchPath, NSObject.FromObject("/usr/local/bin/true"));
```

These fail with random errors like:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
```

or:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
```

Stack trace is not very helpful either:

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x101db9369 - My.app: mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x101dace9e - My.app: mono_handle_native_crash
    0x101d23216 - My.app: altstack_handle_and_restore
    0x7fff688e7817 - /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : objc_msgSend
    0x101ccf6cc - My.app: xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend
```

Clearly if `RespondsToSelector` returns `true` then the object should respond to the message?
Is there a way to find out if the argument type and value are correct, or otherwise deduct what is causing the crash?

Comment: Pass the argument as `NSString` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsstring?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12 Btw `launchPath` is deprecated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask/1414221-launchpath . You should be using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask/1408983-arguments instead (first element of the array is equivalent to launchPath)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Setting `LaunchPath` is sadly still required on Xamarin.Mac. If you don't set it, it throws 'NSInvalidArgumentException: launch path not accessible;' upon calling `Launch()`.